# Kubuntu 15.10: Steam not launching

Tags: kubuntu, steam

Anytime I try to launch steam it doesn't start and this comes up in the terminal:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.10 64-bit  
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically  
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)  
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so  
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I am very new to Linux and I am running Kubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would help since this is a solution for those running ArchLinux, but if you've got nothing else to lose:

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=193802

removing some files got it working for these users.